# A business-like, formal synonym for the term "worked out and honed” a solution

Tags: synonyms, formality

I'm an IT worker who is trying to emphasize how I have a "WORKED OUT" solution to something, but the term seems so elementary and unprofessional. I thought about "configured" or "fully configured", but none emphasized the importance of the solution being "worked out" (meaning it has gone through iterations, fixing, and amendments).

**UPDATE**
To emphasize my use case: 
I intended this to be for a bullet point in a presentation: "- A worked out technical specification document". I wanted to emphasize that the technical document we created took a few attempts/iterations. The "extra effort" of iterations was my main point for the word "worked out"

Comment: To work out **a** solution to a problem is very good English. The term is neither elementary nor unprofessional, for your information.

Comment: To find a solution to a  problem/issue [like a bug]  is the same thing.

Comment: You do not have a worked-out solution: you have a solution worked out.

Comment: @tchrist so is the term "Worked-out solution" incorrect? I've used it often, so I wanted to confirm, lol. very good point though, thanks!  I thought you could always use that as an adjective

Comment: Also, I don't understand why my question is voted down. The down voted questions are often OMITTED in searches, so people will re-ask the same question over and over again.

Comment: Did [none of these](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/worked%20out?s=t) help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a **consensus** or **vetted** solution? The bullet on you PowerPoint slide could read:

- Developed a **consensus** technical specification document

  OR
- Developed (and) **vetted** technical specification document

Each of these indicates that you didn't develop the document by yourself in a vacuum without input from others, but that you went the *extra mile* to obtain input/feedback, and you used that input/feedback to improve the document through an *iterative process*. Such a process is implicit in both **consensus** and **vetted**. After all, you're a *team player*, and you're dedicated to producing *quality products*, i.e., to *truly-worked-out solutions*.

From Dictionary.com:

> **vet**: to appraise, verify, or check for accuracy, authenticity, validity, etc.: *An expert vetted the manuscript before publication.*
>
> **consensus**: general agreement or concord; harmony.

In my experience (and I've developed many technical specifications documents):

- **Vetted**  means I have worked closely with my team, experts, and/or stakeholders, etc. and revised the putative solution based on their
  input. I've worked it out not just by myself, but with others whose
  views matter. **Vetting** generally requires multiple iterations
  (including revisions, fixes, amendments, etc.).
- **Consensus** means I have worked with my team, experts, and/or with stakeholders, etc. to develop a mutually agreed-upon solution.
  Again, I've worked it out not just by myself, but with others whose
  views matter. The development of **consensus** generally requires
  multiple iterations.

Comment: I chose this answer because it touched on all points and was the most relevant. Thanks everyone though

Answer (score 2):

You have ***developed*** a solution.

M-W:

> **[develop](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/develop)**
>   *transitive verb*
>
> **2 b** :  to **create or produce** especially **by deliberate effort over time** :
>   develop new ways of doing business; **develop software**
>
> Scientists are developing a treatment for the disease.
>
> The company has developed a new method for recycling old tires.

Comment: Thank you, I intend this to be for a PowerPoint presentation. And one bullet point was this: "Worked out technical specification document". I wanted to emphasize that the technical document we created took a few attempts/iterations. The "extra effort" of iterations was my main point for the word "worked out"

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep it simple and say you have a **[tested](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20tested) solution**?

> take measures to check the quality, performance, or reliability of
>   (something), especially before putting it into widespread use or
>   practice.
>
> *"this range has not been tested on animals"*
>
> **synonyms:** try out, put to the test, put through its paces, experiment with, pilot; check, examine, assess, evaluate, appraise,
>   investigate, analyze, scrutinize, study, probe, explore, trial;
>   sample; screen; *technical* assay
>
> **"a small-scale prototype was tested"**

In terms of software, you might also say your solution is **[fully tested](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=fully+tested)**.

You also might say you have a **[robust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_(computer_science)) solution**:

> In computer science, robustness is the ability of a computer system to cope with errors during execution and cope with erroneous input.

Comment: Just because something has been worked out doesn't mean it's been tested, nor that it is robust. Once @LearnByReading attempts to try his solution, he may find it falls apart very easily.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I don't disagree with you, and I feel like OP is looking for a bit of an optimistic word given the nature of software. But I'm working from the **meaning it has gone through iterations, fixing, and amendments** part of OP's question.

Comment: Thank you both for very valid points - yes, I was looking for a positive spin, but I'm too weary of the word "tested" given that typically implies a lot in the field of computer science (it effectively says that we've moved to the next iteration in the lifecycle, which is not true)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you have "refined" a solution?

The use of "refined" would suggest an *extended process* of fixing something - that it, going through several iterations and amendments while working out the problem, as you noted you were using "worked out" to mean, instead of simply thought out or discovered.

One of the definitions of refined is "improved to be more precise or exact" (from [Mirriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refined)).  It can also mean "free from impuritites" or "precise to a fine degree" (from [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/refined))

So, if you have been "refining" a solution ever since you found that bug... you have gone through a process of testing, and bettering your proposed solution, not just found something that might work.

Comment: This is the only answer so far that has understood my intention and my real need for synonyms.

Comment: Also, I don't understand why my question is voted down. The down voted questions are often OMITTED in searches, so people will re-ask the same question over and over again.